# ASP.net Web Forms - TextBox displaying wrong encoded text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck on this problem for a while now.
I did some searches on this and other sites, where the problems got solved, but sadly none worked for me.

Problem:

I develope an asp.net web forms application, for a list of reservations.
The name and prename data values can have german symbols in it (ä, ö, ü, ß).
Basically everything worked fine until I added an edit page for the reservations.
When I set the text of a textbox based on the data values, they text shows `&#246;` for ö, `&#228;` for ä, `&#252;` for ü and `&#223;` for ß.
The point is that this only happens in the asp:Textbox.Text, if I use it in a asp:Label.Text it shows the correct name.
So now the question is: Anyone else had this problem and if yes how did you fix it? If not, do you have any ideas how to fix it?

[Code + Result Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaS0p.png)

P.S.: Yes everything is utf-8, yes I tried HttpUtility.Decode and such, nothing worked as said at start. In the database it is shown correct too. I can type in an ö without problem, just setting text doesn't work.

EDIT:

After Sonal Borkar's idea, I used a textarea but it is impossible to check a textarea with a RequiredFieldValidator. So now I was messing around in the .net-API and noticed some things:
Only **listitem.cs** and **textbox.cs** have this `PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.EncodedInnerDefaultProperty),`
set in their text-attribute, things like **label.cs** have `PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)`.
Also listitem.cs and textbox.cs have an override in their ControlBuilder

```
public override bool HtmlDecodeLiterals() {
        // ListItem text gets rendered as an encoded attribute value.
        // At parse time text specified as an attribute gets decoded, and so text specified as a
        // literal needs to go through the same process.

        return true;
    }
```

Other webcontrols like the label, don't override this method and their method returns false.

BUT still it doens't make any sense, because I have ListItem which has a german symbol in it and it gets rendered perfectly fine. So I am really stuck and confused why no one ever had to mess with this before.
Looking for a solution by myself, but still could use some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
After trying around for another few hours, thats the way I made it actually work, if anyone will ever find themselves in the same situation.
In your FormView add an empty TextBox as following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EditName"  runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

In your CodeBehind class, when the page is completely loaded, get your data from the database again, and call a method like this:

```
protected void GetNameAndPreName()
    {
        int reservationID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["reservationID"].ToString());
        ReservationContext _db = new ReservationContext();

        Reservation r = _db.Reservations.SingleOrDefault(reservation => reservation.ReservationID == reservationID);
        (reservationDetail.FindControl("EditName") as TextBox).Text = r.Name;
        (reservationDetail.FindControl("EditPreName") as TextBox).Text = r.PreName;
    }
```

In my case it's name and prename, change to whatever you need. This will the text will be shown correctly.

HINT: This does NOT work for multiline textboxes, as they get encoded everytime as seen in [TextBox Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs,924b63b9e4800e35,references)

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Try below, Good Luck!

1) Use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="EditItem" runat="server" Text="<%# 
     HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Item.Name) %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

2) Set Meta Tag in HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

3) Set Globalization in Web.config

```
 <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" 
  fileEncoding="utf-8" />
```

4) Set the font-family in style of Textbox

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="EditItem" runat="server" Text="<%# 
     HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Item.Name) %>" style="font-family: Courier 
        New;"></asp:TextBox>
```

5) Replace Textbox with TextArea or RichTextBox

Comment: Well now I remember that I tried that too, this is what gets shown: 'S&amp;#246;der'

Comment: 1),2),4) didnt work, 3) is already set and 5) works with textarea, but the textarea is a little bit bugged with placement, seems to be the only working thing so far though. Thanks

Comment: Using css classes on textarea removes the bugged placement!